# Why does my NSMutableURLRequest fail?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to get data from the server but I get error message that `{"Message":"Wrong Process.","Success":false,"Cookie":null}` from the server while I run the same link in the server test client and I get the right result. So please where would be my issue in my code please?

The Key is `data`

The value is `<r_PM act=\"par\"/>`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/service/par.ashx"]];

    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"data=<r_PM act=\"par\"/>"];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[message length]];

    [postRequest addValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [postRequest addValue:msgLength                         forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                    initWithRequest:postRequest
                                    delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                          forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;

    responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSLog(@"responseData is: %@", responseData);

    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: ];

    NSLog(@"Results : %@", newStr);

}
```

Comment: The actual error message was "I wrote wrong thing"?

Comment: Why are you both starting a connection `[connection start]` and performing a `sendSynchronousRequest:` request?

Comment: @Zaph It is written in different language I will edit it. Sorry

Comment: @Zaph This is the first time for me to use `NSURLConnection` and I was searching in `stackoverflow` and I found a similar code. and I have tried it. Thanks for mentioning that I don't need it anymore Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a request whose content-type is XML, but whose request body is not. The "data=..." format is not XML. In the absence of API documentation or sample code that generates a valid request, it's going to be hard for us to help you.

As an aside, your Objective-C code is issuing the request twice, one using the delegate-based `NSURLConnection` (for which you haven't shared your delegate implementation) and then again with `sendSynchronousRequest`. Only issues this once. And if you like the simplicity of the `sendSynchronousRequest` method, I'd suggest you use its `sendAsynchronousRequest` sibling, which is also pretty convenient, but isn't synchronous.

---

Offline, by examining request you were sending from another tool, we confirmed that the issue was that

- Request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not `application/xml`

  Thus, replace `Content-Type` line with:

  ```
  [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  ```
- The data has to be percent escaped, e.g.:

  ```
  NSString *value = @"<r_PM act=\"par\"/>"; 
  NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@", [self percentEscapeString:value]];
  ```

  where, the percent escaping routine might be something like:

  ```
  - (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
  {
      NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                   (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                   (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                   (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                                   kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
      return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
  }
  ```

Comment: So now I've remove `data` and just keep it as `@"<r_PM act=\"par\"/>" & I removed `NSURLConnection` to.  How can I add forKey? I will search about sendAsynchronousRequest.

Comment: Or could you please help me more?

Comment: The "for key" doesn't make sense in the context of XML a request (or at least not in this format). We cannot help you create a valid request unless we know more about what format your web service requires. Show us example code that creates valid request. Or share link to your API's documentation.

Comment: Will this help?

<r_PM act=\"par\"/> Resutl:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root> 
<prts> 
<p symbol="EUR/USD" bid="1.41305" offer="1.41355"/> 
<p symbol="GBP/USD" bid="1.59301" offer="1.59351"/> 
<p symbol="CHF/NOK" bid="0" offer="0"/> 
.
</prts> 
<cvp t="0"/>
</root>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64038/discussion-between-can-and-rob).